# including a header with subfolder

Tags: php

I have some big problems including my header in subfolder. I have a folder structure like this:

[![Folder structure][1]][1]

I would like to include my header in the innovatian-project.php. As I see it, I have to go back three folders to get to the root:

> AU -> Courses -> **Document Root**

I have tried with the following:

- `<?php include '../../../resources/includes/header.php'?>`
- `<?php include(__DIR__.'/resources/includes/header.php'); ?>`
- `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php'); ?>`
- `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/includes/header.php'); ?>`
- `<?php include('../../resources/includes/header.php'); ?>`

But none of this is working. I have tried so many things, that I cannot even remember anymore. Does anybody have an idea on what I can do? The path to the innovation-project is here:

```
<?php include 'resources/includes/header.php' ?>

<body id="services">

<?php include 'resources/includes/navbar.php' ?>

<!-- start intro section -->
<section class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="intro-content">
                    <h1>Mine kompetencer  <strong>strongest </strong></h1>
                    <h2>areas, where I can add the most value to a company </h2>

                    Mine kompetencer er baseret på 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end intro section -->
```

**UPDATE**

When I use the following code, the header, nav and footer is called. But the CSS is not called:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio_da/resources/includes/header.php' ?>

<body id="services">

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio_da/resources/includes/navbar.php' ?>

<!-- start intro section -->
<section class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="intro-content">
                    <h1>Mine kompetencer  <strong>strongest </strong></h1>
                    <h2>areas, where I can add the most value to a company </h2>

                    Mine kompetencer er baseret på 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- end intro section -->

<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Portfolio_da/resources/includes/footer.php' ?>
```

**UPDATE 2 WHERE I CALL THE CSS IN header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>



<!-- Favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">



<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/supersized.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css">

<!-- Main Stylsheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
<!-- Theme Color Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_color.css">

<!-- Google Font -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

</head>
```

Comment: what about doing it this way: `<?php include('resources/includes/navbar.php'); ?>`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried your suggestion, but still the same.

Comment: To include header.php in another script in another file, create absolute path and include it. To do this first get the Document Root and append the header.php path with subfolder and include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/includes/header.php'); ?>`
2. See your php.ini about

> allow_url_include

3. What is in your router file?
4. You have to go up 2 folders.

   `<?php include('../../resources/includes/header.php'); ?>`

UPDATE

Change these lines in header.php: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`

like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/Portfolio_da/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using MAMP, so I just set the phpinfo in another document, there is laying in the same folder as my question. https://vouzalis.com/temp/version2/courses/AU/store-it-innovationer.php - I can see that the allow_url_include is set to off. That should be "on"?

Comment: At first check point 1 and 4. 
If these are not working turn on allow_url_include for a refresh.
Dont forget to restart your apache2.

Comment: Thank you again. 1 and 4 is not working. I tried to find the php.ini, but I searched for allow_url_inside but there was no result. Do you know where I can turn it on?

Comment: allow_url_include, not inside.

Comment: Can you check the apache2 error.log ?
You can turn it on in your apache2 host settings and set the path there too.

Comment: I just checked the log. It says the following:

[Sat Oct 22 11:25:23 2016] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Portfolio_da/courses/AU/css, referer: http://localhost:8888/Portfolio_da/courses/AU/innovation-project.php

I do not know if that make any sense?

Comment: I just made an update on my question. The header, navbar and footer is called now. But the CSS, JS and so on is not called. Does it make any sense the new code?

Comment: In which file do you call the css? Can you update your question with it?

Comment: Thank you again. I just updated my question with the code, where I call my CSS.

Comment: Are you still active on the question here? I have quite a problem, that I did not think off.

Comment: Just ask, I'm here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126393/discussion-between-bela-b-and-ne-kr).

Comment: Okay thank you a lot. The problem is now 3 things. The one is that when I upload my code to my website, not even the frontpage calls the CSS: https://vouzalis.com/ . On localhost the css and js is called, but not the images after I use: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  ?>/vouzalis.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">